# C: Usage of any GPU for parallel calculations

Tags: c, parallel-processing, gpu

I recently wrote some software that makes a lot of calculations.

The calculations are done in levels, while for each level, the calculations within it are independent. I.e. logically, I can run them in parallel, as none of them relies on the result of the others.

My question is: Is there a **general** C library for making parallel math (matrix) operations on the GPU, which works on all the platforms (Windows/Unix/etc.)?

When I say **general** - I mean to some library that would work with any modern GPU

Comment: I think CUDA could be your goal.

Comment: @LP: On ATI? OpenCL is standard. (Yes, Nvidia does not support standards).

Comment: Does CUDA work also for other GPUs? Would it work for Intel GPU?

Comment: You can use OpenCl that can program CPU,GPU,DSP and various other devices. See here https://www.khronos.org/opencl/

Comment: CUDA is anything but a general framework. It is supported solely by nVidia products. As @Olaf said, OpenCL is the standard but it has "language" in its name and the "C" is not THE C.

Comment: The question can be expanded, does a general C library even exist, that supports a wide variety of gpus on the market?

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov: I did not want to imply "CL" means "C-language). "CL" is "computing language" actually. But IIRC, it is _like_ C in Syntax and some semantics. But that would apply to C++, too and this _is_ also a different language.

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov: There might be some wrapper libs for common problems, but if you want to utilize the whole feature set, you have to go native.

Comment: What do you mean by "GPU" (and why GPU)? Do you mean GPGPU? Are you interested with Intel HD graphics which essentially gives you a lot of parallelism on board? Do you care about other kind of "not GPU, but accelerator" platforms like Xeon Phi or FPGA? And do you say running in pararllel on CPU is not interesting or "solved problem" to you?  All in all, the only "general enough" solution is OpenCL, but I'm sure that you may end up with very different  choices, especially in future (AMP, Cilk Plus, CUDA, OpenMP...). To get informed answer - the question needs more details about your goals.

Answer (score 1):

C is a singlethreaded language, to assign your calculations to run in parallel on a GPU, for something like 'oh I don't know' Bitcoin mining, you should consider using the AMP library in C++. I'm not too sure about the whole, compile to run on GPU core thing, but I know that this will certainly perform your calculations in parallel.

Comment: I need something that is cross-platform. I understood that AMP is only for Windows

Answer (score 0):

... off loading bitcoin miners? ;)

& well, if you can compile your source directly on the host machine, then you can specify to the compiler,

```
# IF (some operating system) THEN
```

& that will solve that. Going back to your parallel computing problem, CUDA.h functions will calculate your this and that on the GPU, but that will most likely require some serious jigging if you say that you have already wrote the calculations part of your project.